# Book about a girl who learns she is half Elf, half Human

Tags: story-identification, books, elves

I started reading a fantasy book about 3-4 months ago and for the life of me I can't locate the book in my Kindle or Audible library.

The story is about traveling party of 4-5 characters. One was a male human, one was a female who was half-human and half-elf. One character was an older human male who was a kick-ass fighter and he had to fight off and kill a male warrior elf. He did not want to fight the elf but the elf was very proud and would not relent. The group was being hunted.

The half-human/half-elf female had learned she was a half-elf on the road with the group. She was embraced by a group of elves and they told her about her Elf heritage. The girl had elf-like qualities (was able to move across the earth stealthly) but did not know her heritage until someone in the group told her about her parents.

Her dad was 100% elf and the mom was 100% human. They fell in love against society's wishes and went off to live together. The elf man ended up leaving his human wife and child in order to save his family.

Comment: Your final paragraph was a new (off-topic) question so I've removed it.

Comment: This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure but the book you're looking for might be *[Nijura. Das Erbe der Elfenkrone](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1739655.Nijura_Das_Erbe_der_Elfenkrone)* (*Nijura: The Legacy of the Elf Crown*) by Jenny-Mai Nuyen.

> Thick fog lies over the marshes of Korr. So it happens that the moor elves recognize the veiled visitor to their village only late. The enigmatic man pretends to be the envoy of the Free Elves in the Dark Forests, and so no one suspects when the stranger - albeit in broken elf - asks to speak to the king of the moor elves. Why too? The king of the moor elves is in possession of the Elrysjar crown, which makes him invulnerable. So his subjects let the stranger enter the hut. When he comes out, he drops the hood. It is a human being and he has Elrysjar on his head: an outrageous outrage!

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! Could you explain how this matches the description given in the question? Right now, this is a link-only answer, and if that link ever expires for any reason, your answer will become completely useless.

Comment: This novel appears to only be in German. Is there an English translation version that OP might have read?